# Why can't I use tab expansion/auto-complete of shell variables with cd?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have setup a variable in `.bashrc`:

```
export SOME_DIR=/path/to/some/dir
```

Now, with `ls` I can type `ls $SOME_DIR[tab]` and the variable will be expanded, and I can then use tab for auto-completion when going deeper into the filesystem.
However, if I try `cd $SOME_DIR[tab]` or `cd $SOME_DIR/[tab]`, nothing happens.

Why does this only work with `ls`? Is it possible to make it work with `cd`?
I have tried adding `shopt -s direxpand` to `.bashrc`, to no effect:

Comment: I just tried on a couple different systems and the expansion worked with `cd` exactly as it did with `ls`.  Are you sure you're not losing $SOME_DIR in your testing?  Does `echo $SOME_DIR` still give you what you are expecting?

Comment: As you can see, different shells (with different options) on different OSes might perform differently. What shell on what OS/version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `shopt -s direxpand` works with everything except the built-in `cd`. So I just added `alias xy=cd` to my profile, and `xy` works just like `cd` except `direxpand` works using TAB. (Who would have thought it would be so simple?)

Answer (score 1):

In Cygwin, I had the same issue and had to enclose the shell variable in quotes.  So for example `cd $ccc`  would not expand but `cd "$ccc"` would, and your cursor is still before the right-hand quote.

Comment: Sorry, I have to add that `"$ccc/"` works.  You need that ending `/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have directories in `/path/to/some/dir/`? I just tried `cd $SOME_DIR/[tab]` on my system and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to expand the variable for me is to add a slash at the end of it:

```
$ cd $SOME_DIR[tab] ## fails
$ cd $SOME_DIR/[tab] ## works
```

I get exactly the same behavior with `cd` or `ls`. Could you have added the slash in on and fogoten it in the other?

Answer (score 0):

I get almost the same issue with (old) bash 4.2.37, not with bash 4.3 or 4.4.
That is: expansion works with `ls` but not with `cd`.

---

However, as a helper keybinding, I have defined (from e**S**pand ):

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
Control-s: shell-expand-line
```

That allows me to type: `cd $SOME_DIR` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> to get the variable expanded to:

```
cd /path/to/some/dir
```

---

A keybinding that is equally useful is (from **G**lobbing):

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> also in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
Control-g: glob-expand-word
```

That allows me to type `ls b*` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> to get the `b*` expanded:

```
$ ls b*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>
$ ls bash.html_node.tar.gz bash.pdf
```

Which also allow me to edit the command line and add or remove elements as needed.