# How to expand filenames with Tab, even when a shell variable is used in the path?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

In my `.bash_profile` I set short variables to ease the access to some common directories. For example:

```
lh=/var/log/httpd
hc=/etc/httpd/conf
```

So I use it like this for example:

```
$ cd $lh
$ less $lh/access_log
```

But when I want to use the Tab key in order autocomplete filenames (in such a parameter containing a variable reference), bash performs the autocomplete but 
also inserts a backslash `\` before the dollar sign of the variable name.

For example, typing `less $lh/acc` 
then hitting Tab will expand to: `less \$lh/access_log`.

Of course, what I would like instead is `less $lh/access_log` 
or even `less /var/log/httpd/access_log`.
(weirdly, with the `cd` command the autocomplete doesn't work at all in that case, this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157026/why-cant-i-use-tab-expansion-auto-complete-of-shell-variables-with-cd) already talks about it)

I know that there is an alternative by using `shell-expand-line` (default key: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>), but it's far from 
perfect because it expands aliases as well, and it doesn't quote paths with special chars (spaces, ...).

Is there a way in bash to expand filenames with Tab, even when a shell variable is used in the path?

Comment: if it's about making things easy , why don't  you put your both cmds and vars in one alias ?!; e.g: `alias watchaccess="less $lh/access_log"` .

Comment: Try `shopt -s direxpand`

Comment: by the way maybe something wrong with your bash , because bash expands anykind of path after any command ,

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: that solved the issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was that the shell option `direxpand` was not set. The following solved the issue:

```
shopt -s direxpand
```